# Why is my movement not smooth and jagged?

Tags: unity, 2d, movement, rigidbody

My game isn't smooth, it runs at 60 fps but has quick lag spikes just under every second. I really can't figure out why. I have a feeling it's to do with my player movement code.
My rigidbody's interpolation is set to interpolate, and collision detection to continuous.
Here is a sample of what it looks like. https://gfycat.com/cleanmeagerhuemul

```
public ParticleSystem particleLauncher;

public float playerSpeed;
public float jumpSpeed;
public float coolDownTime = 2;
public CameraShake cameraShake;
public bool dashEnabled;
public bool isCamShakeEnabled;

private bool isJumping;
private float move;
private Rigidbody2D rb;
private bool facingRight;
private float nextDashTime = 0;

public bool movementAllowed;

private Animator anim;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    isCamShakeEnabled = true;
    Scene currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
    string sceneName = currentScene.name;
    dashEnabled = true;
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    facingRight = true;
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}


void FixedUpdate()
{
    if(movementAllowed == true)
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && !isJumping)
    {
        rb.AddForce(new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpSpeed));
        isJumping = true;
    }
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
    if (movementAllowed == true)
    {
        move = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        rb.velocity = new Vector2(move * playerSpeed, rb.velocity.y);


        if (isJumping == true)
        {
            anim.SetBool("isJumping", true);
        }
        if(isJumping == false)
        {
            anim.SetBool("isJumping", false);
        }


        Flip(move);

        if (move == 0)
        {
            anim.SetBool("isRunning", false);
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("isRunning", true);
        }

        if (Time.time > nextDashTime)
        {
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Dash") && dashEnabled == true)
            {
                if(SceneManager.GetActiveScene() == SceneManager.GetSceneByName("Level4-2"))
                {
                    nextDashTime = Time.time + coolDownTime;
                    StartCoroutine("DashMove");
                }
                else
                {
                    nextDashTime = Time.time + coolDownTime;
                    StartCoroutine("DashMove");
                    StartCoroutine(cameraShake.Shake(.10f, .3f));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene() == SceneManager.GetSceneByName ("Level5-4"))
    {
        dashEnabled = false;
        isCamShakeEnabled = false;
    }

    if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene() == SceneManager.GetSceneByName("Level5-4"))
    {
        isCamShakeEnabled = false;
    }
}



void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.transform.CompareTag("killer"))
        gameObject.GetComponent<TrailRenderer>().enabled = false;
}




IEnumerator DashMove()
{
    playerSpeed += 60;
    particleLauncher.Emit(30);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.07f);
    playerSpeed -= 60;
}


void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
    {
        isJumping = false;
        gameObject.GetComponent<TrailRenderer>().enabled = true;
    }

    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("BK"))
    {
        isJumping = false;
    }

    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("MGround"))
    {
        this.transform.parent = other.transform;
        isJumping = false;
    }

    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Mcircle"))
    {
        this.transform.parent = other.transform;
        isJumping = false;
    }
}

void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("MGround"))
    {
        this.transform.parent = null;
        isJumping = true;
    }

    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Mcircle"))
    {
        this.transform.parent = null;
        isJumping = true;
    }

    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
    {
        isJumping = true;
    }

    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("BK"))
    {
        isJumping = false;
    }
}

private void Flip(float move)
{
    if (move > 0 && !facingRight || move < 0 && facingRight)
    {
        facingRight = !facingRight;

        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;

        theScale.x *= -1;

        transform.localScale = theScale;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you lagging in editor mode or after building it? Also, can you provide a gif sample of your problem?

Comment: When you have to troubleshoot performance problems in Unity, then it is usually good to know how to use the [Profiler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html).

Comment: One more thing. I would put all the movement code in fixedUpdate function, not in both update and fixedUpdate.

Comment: It's not bad to put instantaneous actions like the start of a dash in Update (though you should use `StartCoroutine(DashMove())` rather than using reflection to get the method by name). Can you confirm how you've configured your character's Rigidbody interpolation, and any follow camera logic? These are common places to introduce judder that looks superficially similar to a framerate stutter.

Comment: @A.Gerber I lag both in editor and building, i can for sure add a gif sample, but how would i post that on here. apologies im new to the site.

Comment: @DMGregory for scenes i use camera follow i store all script in late update and it only follows the player on the x axis by using the .x function on a vector3 called temp, so temp.x = the transform of the player's position.x

Comment: That's half of what I asked you. Don't forget to include your Rigidbody configuration, and the profiling information you were asked for earlier. Once you have this information ready, add it to your question using the `Edit` link. You can visit the [help center](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for guidance on formatting, inserting images/gifs, etc.

Comment: For gif: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/404/how-to-post-gifs-on-this-site

Comment: thank you @A.Gerber https://gfycat.com/cleanmeagerhuemul i dont know if you can tell from the gif as it's more subtle compared to the raw footage.

Comment: Add it to your post so everyone can see it :)

Comment: @Philipp i tried using the profiler, but it seems the issue isn't to do with any form of performance from what i can see

Comment: @DMGregory my rigidbody's interpolation is set to interpolate. Collision detection is set to continuous and rotation on the z axis is frozen if that helps at all.

Comment: Again, please edit this information into your question, not in the comment thread.

Comment: @DMGregory I also suspect the issue is the camera follow logic. Late update is the place where it should be as the interpolation step on a rigidbody will be concluded at that point so the camera can use the interpolated position correctly.

Comment: @Weaver Unless the camera itself has a rigidbody...